# How to get deleted or inserted item from proxy array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, es6-proxy

I am trying to detect changes in an array of objects using JavaScript proxies.

**Problem:** Any time there is a change in array like deletion or insertion, i want to get that deleted or inserted item.

**Current Code**

```
target = [{ id: 1, a: 'a' }, { id: 2, a: 'b' }];
proxy = new Proxy(target, {
    get: function (target, property: string, receiver) {
        if (property === 'pop') {
            console.log('deleted object', target[target.length - 1]);
        }
        console.log('get', property);
        // property is index in this case
        return target[property];
    },
    set: function (target, property, value, receiver) {
        console.log('set', property, 'to', value);
        target[property] = value;
        // you have to return true to accept the changes
        return true;
    }
});
```

**Current Thoughts:**
I did a little workaround to get the deleted item from array but it only works for `pop()` method because it deletes the last item from array. But i need a way to get the changes even it is made using `splice` method or `push` or `pop`.

Thanks.

**[Update]**
**Solution I Found:**

https://github.com/ElliotNB/observable-slim 
I used this library to detect changes in array, i am able to detect changes on nested properties inside array too. This is exactly what i was looking for.

The reason i am using this library is because it's using proxies.

Comment: If you want to capture `splice`, then you'll have to write a handler for splice just like you did for `pop` - look at the arguments to see what will be deleted and then and store the data before it's deleted. Rinse and repeat for every method you want to handle.

Comment: I tried but i didn't get the splice arguments inside this proxy handler.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/underscore-observe
There was this library to observe changes in the array but this is using Array.observe() which is now Obsolete. and proxies are alternative for Array.observe so there should be a way to detect these changes using proxies.

Comment: @JoharZaman is Proxy important to you ? or any other way will be fine also ?

Comment: You shouldn't be tracking method calls at all, you only should be tracking indexed elements.

Comment: @shajji Actually i  am observing changes in individual objects inside array using proxies so it will be good for me if i can detect array changes with proxies too. But if you have any other solution which solve my problem i will look into it and see if it can work for me or not.

Comment: @Bergi i have also tried to track index but when i use splice on proxyArray it is not returning the index of deleted item. I think because it have to rearrange the positions so it get all the indexes of array.

Comment: @JoharZaman Yes, you will need to track rearrangements as well, it's the only reliable way. Arrays aren't interacted with only through their methods.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend not to expose actual traget on getter. You can create a wrapper function to support the cutosom modifier. Check out the below example.

```js
const target = [
  { id: 1, a: "a" },
  { id: 2, a: "b" },
];
const proxy = new Proxy(target, {
  get: function (target, property, receiver) {
    switch (property) {
      case "push":
      case "pop":
      case "slice":
      case "splice":
        return (...arg) => target[property](...arg);
    }
    throw Error("Not supported yet");
  },
});

proxy.push({ id: 3, a: "c" })
console.log(proxy.pop())
console.log(proxy.slice(1,2))
console.log(proxy.pop())
```

Comment: This is pretty much no longer an array. Neither `proxy.length` nor `proxy[0]` work.

Answer (score 0):

Refer the below code for reference :

```js
function observeArrayChanges(array, callback) {
  // Create a proxy for the array
  const arrayProxy = new Proxy(array, {
    // The set handler is called whenever there's an insertion or deletion
    set(target, property, value) {
      const oldValue = target[property];

      // Perform the actual insertion or deletion
      const result = Reflect.set(target, property, value);

      // Check if it's an insertion or deletion
      if (oldValue !== value) {
        // Call the callback with information about the change
        callback({
          type: oldValue === undefined ? 'insert' : 'delete',
          item: oldValue === undefined ? value : oldValue,
        });
      }

      // Return the result of the set operation
      return result;
    },
  });

  return arrayProxy;
}

// Example usage:

const myArray = observeArrayChanges(
  [{ id: 1, a: 'a' }, { id: 2, a: 'b' }],
  (change) => {
    console.log(`Change type: ${change.type}`);
    console.log(`Changed item: `, change.item);
  }
);

// Insert an item
myArray.push({ id: 3, a: 'c' });

// Delete an item
//delete myArray[0];
console.log(myArray.pop())
console.log(myArray.slice(1,2))
console.log(myArray.pop())
console.log(myArray.length)
console.log(JSON.stringify(myArray))
```